# SQL query to generate possible combinations from alternate names

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in a table that consists of semicolon-separated product names like 'A;B;C', 'X;Y', 'B;A;Z;T' etc .
In another table, I have the mapping of product_name and alternate_name. Below is the data of alternate_data table

```
Product_name  Alternate_name
A              A
A              2
B              B
B              4
C              C
C              6
C              7
```

In the above table, product_name can be the same as alternate_name as well.

I want to generate all possible combinations of product names using alternate names. The expected output for 'A;B;C' is as below

```
A;B;C
A;B;6
A;B;7
A;4;C
2;B;C
A;4;6
A;4;7
2;B;6
2;B;7
2;4;C
2;4;6
2;4;7
```

How to generate all the above possible combinations?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple brands of SQL database. Tag the one you are using and want a solution for.

Comment: Is it always groups of three? I suspect not.

Comment: @shawnt00 :  group can be of any size like 'A;B;C' , 'X;Y' , 'B;A;Z;T' etc

Comment: Multiple products in one string? That violates first normal down and is a terrible database design. The first step will hence be to split the strings into rows. Do you know how to do that? Or can you change the database design and fix this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I can convert semi-colon-separated values into rows. I am getting these values from 3rd party.

Comment: The answer given by @p3consulting seems to me the most appropriate to your request. However, i think, the size of such a table will be gigantic. For example, for a group of 4 products with a total of 100 products by 3 alternatives on 1 product, the table size will be about 10,000,000.

Comment: Perhaps you can translate a looping SQL Server approach into something useful for you. It's mostly based around string replacement. https://dbfiddle.uk/Ls401nSf

Answer (score 0):

Given a specific group size (e.g. 3), you could accomplish this using cartesian products of subsets, such as:

```
with
    a as (select alternate_name from alternate_data where product_name = 'A'),
    b as (select alternate_name from alternate_data where product_name = 'B'),
    d as (select alternate_name from alternate_data where product_name = 'C')
select
    a.alternate_name,
    b.alternate_name,
    c.alternate_name
from
    a full join b full join c
order by
    1, 2, 3
```

But you stated later that the groups can be any arbitrary length, and that sort of variation is not something SQL is well suited to

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with alternatives(Product_name, Alternate_name) as (
    select 'A', 'A' from dual union all
    select 'A', '2' from dual union all
    select 'B', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'B', '4' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'C' from dual union all
    select 'C', '6' from dual union all
    select 'C', '7' from dual -- union all
)
, products(id, names) as (
    select 1, 'A;B;C' from dual union all
    select 2, 'B;A' from dual
)
, expanded(lvl, pnames, name, alternate_name) as (
    select lvl, names, name, alternate_name from (
        select level as lvl, names, regexp_substr(names,'[^;]+',1,level) as name
        from products
        connect by level <= regexp_count(names,';')+1 and id = prior id and prior sys_guid() is not null
    )
    join alternatives on name = product_name
)
, rebuild(lvl, pnames, names) as (
    select lvl, pnames, alternate_name
    from expanded where lvl = 1

    union all
    
    select e.lvl, r.pnames, r.names || ';' || e.alternate_name
    from rebuild r
    join expanded e on e.lvl = r.lvl + 1
)
select names from rebuild
where lvl = regexp_count(pnames,';')+1
;


B;A
B;2
B;B
B;4
4;A
4;2
4;B
4;4
2;A;C
2;A;6
2;A;7
2;2;C
2;2;6
2;2;7
2;B;C
2;B;6
2;B;7
2;4;C
2;4;6
2;4;7
A;A;C
A;A;6
A;A;7
A;2;C
A;2;6
A;2;7
A;B;C
A;B;6
A;B;7
A;4;C
A;4;6
A;4;7
```